# html table font size within cell

Tags: xhtml

Is it possible to change the font size of different lines within a table cell? (While keeping to xhtml strict)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Sam: Yes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <span style="font-size: 10px">10px</span>, <span style="font-size: 14px">14px</span>,  <span style="font-size: 21px">21px</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```